# extend CKEditor image2 widget with the link dialog

Tags: ckeditor

I want to create a CKEditor widget that holds, among others, an image and a link.

Does the widget and dialog API enable extending/reusing an existing widget (in this case, the image2 widget) by reusing another existing dialog (in this case, the link widget) ?